# "Derivation" of Minkowski metric?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, metric-tensor

Is there a deeper meaning behind the the Minkowski metric?

Does it just come from the SR formulae? Or is there some deeper geometrical meaning, maybe in the context of GR?

Comment: It is the unique metric (up to multiplication) preserved by Lorentz transformations. Is that the kind of meaning you are looking for? (I don't know what you say when you say that it "just comes from the SR formulae". To me, all SR formulae follow from the Minkowski metric)

Comment: It comes out as a convenient way to formulate the transformation laws.

Comment: According to this, the metric functions as a generalization from space to space-time, and the final paragraphs discuss use in GR: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/metric.html.  And here is a clear summary of how it works that may reveal something deeper: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskiMetric.html.  But this may be basic and not very helpful.

Comment: Is there a deeper meaning behind the preservation of a quantity like the metric, which basically means that space and time are homogeneous and isotropic and that there is this deep connection between two physical quantities that couldn't be any more different? To me, yes, because I don't know what causes this symmetry to be so well preserved and I am not aware that there is a trivial answer to that, at this point. Space and time could be a jumbled mess, but they aren't. Something has to be responsible for that and whatever  that is leaves its marks in the metric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general relativity, the Minkowski metric plays a privileged role because it is the unique asymptotically flat solution to the vacuum Einstein equations that has zero [ADM energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism#ADM_energy). The [positive energy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_energy_theorem) in general relativity says all asymptotically flat spacetimes satisfying the dominant energy condition have non-negative ADM energy.  Thus, one can think of Minkowski space as the true vacuum state for (asymptotically flat) general relativity, since it is the state with the lowest energy.

Comment: Aha, yes, good point! I now wish I had included that in my answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

If we restrict ourselves to special relativity then the form of the Minkowski metric is an assumption. You can argue whether it is derived from the Einstein postulates or whether the Einstein postulates are derived from it, but this is really a philosophical nicety as you end up having to make equivalent assumptions either way.

If you consider general relativity then the Minkowski metric is derived in the sense that it is (one of) [the solution(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_%28general_relativity%29) to the [vacuum Einstein equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations#Vacuum_field_equations). I suppose the next question is how the Einstein equations are derived, and again this is a somewhat ambiguous question. I would guess most relativists would regard the [Einstein-Hilbert action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) as the fundamental assumption from which general relativity and therefore ultimately the Minkowski metric is derived.

Comment: If you use GR you still have to postulate the pesky minus sign, which is probably what OP's real question is.

Comment: Question: "asperanz" wrote about a UNIQUE flat solution and you wrote about ONE OF the solutions. How must I read this?

Comment: @VeronicaNoordzee There are many vacuum solutions. What asperanz is saying is that only one of these vacuum solutions has a zero ADM energy, and that solution with zero ADM energy is the Minkowski metric. This is what makes the Minkowski metric unique.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, John.

Comment: @John Rennie, For these matters, a reference would be helpful. For example, where can one learn that, "There are many vacuum solutions. What asperanz is saying is that only one of these vacuum solutions has a zero ADM energy, and that solution with zero ADM energy is the Minkowski metric. "